# Attach function call to event attachment calls method immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, events, click

I have a dynamic HTML element and I want to attach a function to the event handler.

```
drilldownTextInput = $("<input type='text' class='drilldown-search' data-drilldown-options='" + drilldownOptions + "' />");
drilldownTextInput.on('click', showOptions());

function showOptions() {
    console.log("Working.");
}
```

The problem is that on page load the `showOptions()` function is called **immediately** and not on the click event.

If I do this, the event works as expected - only on click.

```
drilldownTextInput = $("<input type='text' class='drilldown-search' data-drilldown-options='" + drilldownOptions + "' />");
drilldownTextInput.on('click', function() {
    console.log("Only appears on click...");
});
```

What is the difference between the two and how can I invoke a function in order to keep things DRY?

Comment: If you have `foo(bar())`, then `bar` is called first and its returned value is passed to `foo`. All arguments are evaluated first.

Answer (score 1):

`()` calls a function, you should just pass the function without executing it otherwise the returned value of the function is set as the handler.

```
drilldownTextInput.on('click', showOptions);
```

Comment: Huh - I honestly never knew that. Thank you for your help, it makes sense once you say it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
drilldownTextInput.on('click', showOptions);
```

instead of :

```
drilldownTextInput.on('click', showOptions());
```

[Reference](https://api.jquery.com/on/)